# JavaFX: Getting Stage of running Applications

Tags: java, javafx

For testing a application with TestFX i need to get the actual primary stage of a running application. This means that i haven't the code, i can just run the application through a jar.

Is there any possible solution for this? Scenic View does this already, but i was not able to reproduce this functionallity, especially because it seems that they use the deprecated funtion

```
Windows.impl_getWindows
```

which is not working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import com.sun.javafx.robot.impl.FXRobotHelper;

static Collection<Stage> getAllJavaFXStages() {
    try {
        return FXRobotHelper.getStages();
    } catch ( NullPointerException npe ) {
        // nasty NPE if no stages exist
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

```

Based on my own testing framework code: [Automaton](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/athaydes/automaton/FXAutomaton.groovy).

**EDIT**:

If you want to get a Stage from a different JVM instance than where you're running your code, then there's no simple way.

You're right, [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) does it, but it uses `tools.jar` to do it. This is not a standard jar you get in your runtime, so you must add it manually (placing it in `jre/lib/ext` should do it, you'll normally find it in `lib` only).

I tracked down the code where ScenicView seems to be doing it in their [BitBucket repo.](https://bitbucket.org/scenicview/scenic-view/src/9c93e111e09380a2f42e35cfd7a19573c48649ab/src/org/fxconnector/remote/RemoteConnectorImpl.java?at=default)

Check the function `getRunningJavaFXApplications` for example.

Have fun using that in your tests!

Comment: It's not very good to rely on `com.sun` classes, but for this kind of unsupported functionality that you need (to be able to test stuff) that's the only way AFAIK.

Comment: For the interested reader there is some background discussion on the [perils of using `com.sun` here](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/how-java-9-and-project-jigsaw-may-break-your-code/) (not that I have any better solution).

Comment: I think that with Window.impl_getWindows() and your suggestion you can only get the stages that are started with the application in the same JVM. But my problem is, that the application is running in another JVM.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could find out how ScenicView does it! In their docs they mention you need tools.jar for auto-discovery (it contains JDK internal classes that help tools like IDEs and monitoring of a JVM)... so it is definitely some tools magic.

Comment: Reference to tools.jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html.

Comment: I think I've found it!!! https://bitbucket.org/scenicview/scenic-view/src/9c93e111e09380a2f42e35cfd7a19573c48649ab/src/org/fxconnector/remote/RemoteConnectorImpl.java?at=default

Comment: Good luck using RMI to "attach" to other JVMs :)